# Como colocar um Alerta ao clicar para sair do App

Tags: java, android

Alguns Apps ao sair pelo botão físico do aparelho aparece uma barra abaixo no primeiro clique do usuário, pedindo ao usuário para clicar novamente para sair.

Como faço para programar esse evento?